# Why isn't the server returning anything?

Tags: android, http, return

I used the following piece of code to retrieve basically a JSON formatted String from a php page (www.ace.ucv.ro/android/android.php).

For some reason, no matter what I try, the string "result" remains empty, nothing is stored inside it, even when I use a special function to convert it from InputStream to String (with BufferedReader).

The String in which I want to store is called "RESULT".

```
public void connect(String url){
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
         HttpResponse response;

         try{
             response = client.execute(httpGet);

             Log.i("Praeda", response.getStatusLine().toString());

             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

             if(entity != null){
                 result = entity.getContent().toString();
             }

             if(entity == null){
                 result = "failed";
             }
             }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

Any suggestions you might have would be great...

Comment: Have you verified that the server is indeed sending the JSON you think it is sending?

Comment: The page it generates is just HTML with a String that is a valid JSON. (Tested, so it's a valid JSON). The problem is it doesn't get ANY content from the page: www.ace.ucv.ro/android/android

Comment: Could it be that the data might be too long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON response is normally gzipped, try this

```
jsonResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gin));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    jsonResponse.append(line);
}
reader.close();
```

Comment: I'll give it a try as soon as possible! Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Used a StringBuilder! Anyway, thanks a lot for your help! It was a huge help for me!