# No response when doing an HttpPost using JSON

Tags: android, json, web-services, http-post

I have a submit button created in which I am calling a method "call2" that contains the code
to do an HttpPost using JSON

```
      final Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
      submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v)
          {

            // Perform action on click
             Toast.makeText(display.this,"You have selected to submit data of students",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             call2();           
          }

      });      

   } //OnCreate method ends

  After that I have my call2 method as follows:

       public String call2()
        {
      String result="";
      HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/enterdata/Service1.asmx");
          HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

       try
     {


     JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(items2);
     jsArray.put(items2);   

     int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 10000;  // = 10 seconds

     HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
     HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);


     httppost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(
     result.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
     HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);

     if(response.toString()=="success")
     {
     System.out.println(response);

     }


    }

     catch(Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();

        } 
     return result;

 }
```

my web service code that returns "success" after inserting the records

```
     public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
     {

    [WebMethod]
    public String put(String value)
    {
        int count=1;
        int rows;

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=student;User ID=sa;Password=123");
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            count++;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
            myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
            myCommand.CommandText = "insert into record values('"+ count +"','" + value + "')";
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = value;
            rows = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }

        return "success";
    }
```

this is log cat after I remove the If statement of my Android code in method call2

```
   11-10 09:19:28.447: INFO/System.out(412):   org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@44f5d6b8
   11-10 09:22:39.957: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(440): No keyboard for id 0
   11-10 09:22:39.957: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(440): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
   11-10 09:22:40.447: DEBUG/dalvikvm(124): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1224 objects / 67584 bytes in 363ms
   11-10 09:22:42.498: DEBUG/dalvikvm(440): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2924 objects / 197768 bytes in 80ms
   11-10 09:22:42.587: INFO/System.out(440): org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@44f357a0
```

Now when I run my code, I am unable to see any response in the logcat. My println statement is not getting executed and I don't know why

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions/timeout's happening? Your println statement is not executing because the response wasn't "success"

Comment: No see this logcat : http://pastie.org/2839910

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As yorkw said, I doubt **response.toString()** gives you the response text.  This is how I usually check my responses:

```
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
{
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    json = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
}
```

Obviously if the response code was not 200 there would be some sort of error handling

Comment: check the logcat I posted. How do I convert the response I am getting to a String to view what exactly it is because toString() seems not to be working?

Comment: did you read my code?  instead of doing response.toString(), do response.GetEntity() first, and then use the EntityUtils.toString() static method to get the json response text from the entity.

Comment: Yes got it !! do I need to write the if condition or can the 2 statements be written without an if block in my case

Comment: I made the changes to my code as per ur post, I executed the code in which I did an SOP(json)...Here is what I got in logcat : http://pastie.org/2839964

Comment: This is a whole different problem, your web service is set up to be a SOAP web service, it does not return JSON, only XML - is it an ASMX file in ASP.NET?  Take a look at raw ASHX handlers to do JSON, or move to something like ASP.NET MVC or WCF Web API to do JSON.

Comment: yes it is ASMX file in ASP.NET. I even posted my web service code above...Can u please tell me a simple way out of this ? should I change the return type of my Web Service method to JSON? How do I use ASHX handlers please can u tell me

Comment: Well, you can create an ASHX file in Visual studio by creating a new "Generic Handler".  This link has a little more info: http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/12/16/httphandler-json-data/  .Basically you just grab the request JSON out of the context.Request object and then you can write JSON back out by using context.Response.Write(jsonText)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4857/discussion-between-parth-90-and-mjmarsh)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the if statement

```
if(response.toString()=="success")
```

You will see the println message in logcat.

BTW, I am highly doubt response.toString() equals "success"

Comment: yes dude I remove the if statement and I got this: 11-10 09:19:28.447: INFO/System.out(412): org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@44f5d6b8
But my web service returns success..I want to get success..how to do that

Comment: Either follow mjmarsh answer or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801112/why-isnt-the-server-returning-anything/7801309#7801309)